# What does hustle-attitude mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I googled it but only got this one: https://hustleandattitude.com/what-is-hustle-attitude/

McFerran continued to operate as a one-woman business until she was making $1 million per month in the fall of 2019. At that point, she went to Craigslist to hire her first employee. From there, she rapidly expanded her team, which has grown to 70 in just two years. Yet McFerran’s **hustle-attitude** is very much alive at Glamnetic: her social media managers still directly message every new Glamnetic follower to strike up a conversation and serve as shopping support.

Source: https://www.forbes.com/sites/alexandrasternlicht/2021/05/21/how-this-27-year-old-grew-false-eyelash-startup-glamnetic-to-50-million-in-yearly-revenue/?sh=b3280e54f9f7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means the woman’s attitude as shown through her hustle. The hyphenation is probably a typographical error.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen the expression, and I don't understand why there's a hyphen there. To me it would be better without the hyphen.

Me: native English speaker and teacher of ESL for 15 years